# How to obtain a sharp corner on smooth surface

Tags: subdivision-surface

Hellow everyone,

How can i obtain a sharp corner on the smooth surface of this model?

I am using a subdivision modifier.

Adding a loop edge creates a "break" on the curve (red arrow).
What's the best workflow?

Thanx.

[image]

[image: My mesh]

Answer (score 2):

Add another Loop between the two loops and slide it closer to the loop you want to be sharper. Use LOOP CUT tool

[image]

Comment: It will "break" the arrow.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to increase the crease on the corners, which could be the easiest solution.

Otherwise you can give the edges of the corner a bevel weight and then add a bevel modifier. The extra edges created by the bevel will keep the geometry there in shape.

Place the bevel modifier above the subdivision, set the amount of edges to two and switch the Limit method to "weight". Under "Geometry" set the outer miter to "patch" so that the subdivision wont create harsh highlights there.

[image: The mesh, edges with bevel weight in blue]

Still, the end result won't be 100% perfect - the topology is not ideal for that, but that's a different story.

Edit: with the shape of the hole it might be a viable solution to modell the car without the lights and use a boolean to cut the hole.

Answer (score -1):

You can try "mark sharp".

While in shade smooth:
In edit mode, select the edges you want to be sharp, then right click and select "mark sharp". Your selected edges will turn blue, but you won't see anything different in object mode.
With your mesh selected, go to the object data properties tab and under "normals" select the box for "auto smooth". Play with the angle until you get the result you want.

[image]